# Ubuntu 20.04 won't wake (or the screens won't wake) after lock screen or any extended time away

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, wakeup

The Specs:

- 5.13.0-30-generic #33~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 7 14:25:10 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Core i5 11600K
- 64GB RAM
- Nvidia GTX 1070

  - Current driver nvidia-driver-510 (proprietary, tested):

The Problem:

- If I lock my computer and don't return for any longer than a few hours the screens won't come back on and I have to hard power down and power back on.
- This happens if I log out and leave it on the log in screen just the same.

More Details:

- I have Automatic Suspend turned off.
- Based on the activity light on the tower, it seems like it's still on.
- Also if I run journalctl after rebooting the logs show as though it was active, what's more the logs have thousands of rows of the following errors.

  - gnome-shell[39085]:
    [4182106:4182106:0220/185219.040851:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(314)]
    [.RendererMainThread-0x2e44004c2a00]
    GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Framebuffer is incomplete: Driver
    does not support this framebuffer configuration.
  - gnome-shell[39085]: [4182106:4182106:0220/185219.040771:ERROR:gl_utils.cc(314)] [.RendererMainThread-0x2e44004c2a00] GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION: Draw framebuffer is incomplete
- This error is much less frequent, but maybe related

  - gnome-shell[39085]: [4182106:4182106:0219/201038.983575:ERROR:angle_platform_impl.cc(44)] renderergl_utils.cpp:188 (ClearErrors): Preexisting GL error 0x00000506 as of ../../third_party/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/gl/TextureGL.cpp, setImageHelper:256.
- And this error is even less frequent, I've only seen it a couple of times, but also possibly relavent

  - gnome-shell[38502]: The program 'gnome-shell' received an X Window System error.
    This probably reflects a bug in the program.
    The error was 'BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)'.
    (Details: serial 19467846 error_code 8 request_code 134 (SYNC) minor_code 16)
    (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
    that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
    To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
    variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
    backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)

What I've Done To Try and Fix It:

- I've switched between all the major Nvidia drivers  going back to 450. I still have the problem.
- I've completely disabled the Suspend functionality.
- I haven't disabled blank screen because I need my screens to go blank after some time so they don't burn as well as to not waste electricity.

Anyway this is driving me bonkers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Before anything else update UEFI.

Comment: yeah, UEFI is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending several days testing different solutions, it's pretty clear that the issue is with any of the Nvidia drivers. I tried every last one available in the additional drivers area (470, 510, 390, 418, 450). The only driver that doesn't cause my issue is the Nouveau driver.

So, that's that I guess, at least until a new driver comes and maybe it comes with a fix.